# Sun LOM KVM not working on Linux

Tags: sun, lom

I have a set of SunFire X2100 and X2200 servers.  If I attempt to use the remote KVM feature from my Ubuntu Linux box, the Java app loads and attempts to connect but receives an "Authentication Error" message.  The same thing works fine from a Windows desktop using IE.  Is there something I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a raft of these, two different revs of iLOM.  The KVM thing has never worked in Firefox, on Windows or Linux, and it requires hand-holding to run in IE -- less so in IE6 than 7.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a webstart java application?  You may want to try starting Firefox from a terminal window; it may dump more debugging info then launching it via the desktop.

Also, what version of the JRE are you using?